# How can I get values with reference to field names from function SUM using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity UserFood, which contains fields that are another entities - Food and User.
When I used just JDBC, I created this query to select totals from Food searching by user id and date:

```
"SELECT SUM(f.calories * uf.count) AS total_calories, ROUND(SUM(f.protein * uf.count),1) AS total_protein, ROUND(SUM(f.fat * uf.count),2) AS total_fat, ROUND(SUM(f.carbohydrate * uf.count),2) AS total_carbohydrate FROM users_food uf INNER JOIN food f ON uf.food_id = f.food_id WHERE uf.user_id = ? AND uf.date_added = ?;"
```

Then I could put result to Map, where keys I could set as field name from a table (total_calories, total_protein, total_fat, total_carbohydrate)

How can I do the same with JPA(without Hibernate and Spring)?

I have tried to get at least values from function SUM, but got error.
Below what I have tried to do:

```
public List findFoodFieldsTotalsByUserIdAndDate(Integer userId, LocalDate date) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    Query query = em.createQuery
            ("SELECT SUM(Food.calories * uf.count) AS total_calories, SUM(Food.protein * uf.count) AS total_protein, SUM(Food.fat * uf.count) AS total_fat, SUM(Food.carbohydrate * uf.count) AS total_carbohydrate FROM UserFood uf WHERE uf.user.id = :userId AND uf.dateAdded = :date");

    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
    query.setParameter("date", date);

    List resultList = query.getResultList();

    transaction.commit();
    em.close();
    factory.close();
    return resultList;
    }
```

I know that mistake somewhere exactly in query, because I have created more simple method and there all works great:

```
public List<UserFood> findByUserIdAndDate(Integer userId, LocalDate date) {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
    transaction.begin();

    TypedQuery<UserFood> query = em.createQuery
            ("SELECT uf FROM UserFood uf WHERE uf.user.id = :userId AND uf.dateAdded = :date", UserFood.class);
    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
    query.setParameter("date", date);
    List<UserFood> userFoodList = query.getResultList();

    transaction.commit();
    em.close();
    factory.close();
    return userFoodList;
}
```

Below my Entities:

UserFood:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_food")
public class UserFood {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_food_id")
private int id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_fk_id")
private User user;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "food_fk_id")
private Food food;

private int count;

@Column(name = "date_added")
private LocalDate dateAdded;
}
```

User:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "user_id")
private int id;

@Column(unique = true)
private String login;

@Column(length = 12)
private String password;

private LocalDate birthday;

private int height;

private int weight;

@Column(name = "norma_calories")
private int normaCalories;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "activity_type_fk_id")
private ActivityType activityType;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "role_fk_id")
private Role role;
}
```

Food:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Entity
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = "findAllFood", query = "FROM Food f")})
public class Food {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "food_id")
private int id;

private String name;

private int calories;

@Column(precision = 1)
private double protein;

@Column(precision = 1)
private double fat;

@Column(precision = 1)
private double carbohydrate;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you keep your SQL query and execute it with EntityManager.createNativeQuery()?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yes thank you, I could obtain values with createNativeQuery. But I thought that there was a more elegant way... Obtain values directly to map with field names from table/entity... Or something like that. But if not - thank you one more time for this option. :)

Comment: Maybe http://simasch.github.io/qlrm/ could be helpful to get objects as the result